# How to check the validity of an AES algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, validation, encryption, aes

I use a code who do AES encoding, and I use it for more than 10 years. The problem i don't know if this code is well written or not! The algorithm was written more than 15 years ago, is very tiny (only one hundred of lines) and can compile on ios/android/windows 32bit-64bit/MacOs.

For example in the code i saw that :

- The password is hashed with MD5 (so in 16 bytes) before to be send to the encryption algorithm. I can of course change this part easily but what other algorithm to use ? SHA2 ?
- The iV is initialized with current time, and then the first block of the compression output is the iV (so it's public). Don't know if it's good or bad !
- What else i need to check ?

Now how can i check the validity of the output to know if everything work as expected ?

Comment: You could initialize the algorithm under the same conditions as a well-known implementation, and ensure both produce the same output.

Comment: Also definitely stop hashing passwords with MD5- you can "crack" a MD5 hash with just a quick google search. Use something like bcrypt instead.

Comment: If I got you correctly, you are not worried about the AES algorithm itself but on how it is used in your application?

Comment: @DillonDavis: I know about bcrypt, however Here i don't want to make the encryption slower (purpose of Bcrypt), instead i would prefer to make the password more bigger (ex 256 bits)

Comment: @Henry: yes, but i m also a little worried about the AES algorithm fs it's well written end really encode like aes must do

Answer (score 1):

> use a code who do AES encoding, and I use it for more than 10 years. The problem i don't know if this code is well written or not!

It is called encryption. And from the question ( ~ 100 lines) I assume you'd like to validate a code which is using AES encryption, not the AES encryption itself. I wrote a small [blog about encryption](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/). It is focused on Java, but principles are universal

> The password is hashed with MD5 (so in 16 bytes) before to be send to the encryption algorithm. I can of course change this part easily but what other algorithm to use ? SHA2 ?

Do you mean - hash of the password is used as an encryption key? (I see that often)
If that's the case, it may be not sufficient today. If the passwords are human-provided (not long random data with high entropy), it's better to use some [PBKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) to generate an encryption key from a password.

> The iV is initialized with current time, and then the first block of the compression output is the iV (so it's public). Don't know if it's good or bad !

IV needs to be unique and may be public. Some encryption modes (e.g. CBC) requires IV to be unpredictable (random)

> What else i need to check ?

You may check if the AES implementation itself is provided by some mature library/framework to prevent some side-channel attacks.

As well data should be authenticated (signed, appended hash, ..) to prevent maleability (it is called [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption))

> Now how can i check the validity of the output to know if everything work as expected ?

well - it's only you who can tell of the output is correct or not.

Comment: "I assume you'd like to validate a code which is using AES encryption, not the AES encryption itsel" ... no no the code do the AES encryption itself from 0, this why i like it, it's tiny and simple and without any dependancy and work on all platform

Comment: "Do you mean - hash of the password is used as an encryption key? (I see that often)" yes exactly, but i i don't want to use stuff like PBKDF that simply slow down the key generation. instead i prefere to force user to choose a minimum  32 bytes passwords

Comment: @loki: to evaluate AES implementation itself against side-channel attacks you'd need a lot pretty hefty cryptography backround and knowing the algorithm inside out. This is a nice tiny implementation (https://rweather.github.io/arduinolibs/AES128_8cpp_source.html) and I feel confident in cryptography, yet not competent to evaluate if the algorithm is safe against e.g. timing or power-consumption attacks. Are you sure it's what are you looking for?

Comment: `i prefere to force user to choose a minimum 32 bytes password` Users will thank you for sure. Until you cannot guarantee the password is having high entryopy (e.g. generated by a password manager, ..), human-entered passwords tend to be short and having low entropy and relatively easy to guess. PBKDF is just a workaround to slow down brute-forcing, not a really a full solution.

Comment: no i mean the password is hard coded in the app, I use AES just to encrypt some data of the app, so I can choose a very hard password (of course someone can disassemble the app the find the pwd but this is another problem)

Comment: If your password is in the app it don't really matter if you use MD5 or PBKDF on it before encrypting, or you just write the actually key in the app .. all the methods give the same level of in-security.